# Is masturbation permissible if marriage is not likely to occur?

Tags: sex, disability

I am a young person female who have muscular dystrophy which means I can't move my body and 90% depending on everything wheelchair bound. So my problem is that I  have started get feeling sexual and I know that I won't be getting married to anyone due time illness and zina is a big sin and there is no option for that.

But the feelings are getting stronger for me day by day, I have read that those who can't afford to get married should fast by hadith but I can't even do that due to my genetic disease also Masturbation in Islam is forbidden then what should I do I  am getting very upset now a days & frustrated

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a Hanafi fatwa on masturbation:

> It is only allowed in the very rare situation where if the person did not do this, they would fall into actual zina (i.e. unlawful sexual intercourse), because of their uncontrollable desire, on condition that they are unable to marry and have taken all reasonable means to lessen their passion (such as fasting, lowering their gaze...).
>
> Even in such cases, it could only be done to lessen sexual desire, not for sexual gratification. Otherwise, it would remain sinful. These conditions are extremely rare.

There are also opinions within the Hanbali madhab (ibn Taymiyyah, for example) that say that masturbation is forbidden unless one has a fear of zina and they cannot marry.

I cannot give a ruling on this, but this is some advice based on what I have researched.

Source:
https://archive.islamonline.net/?p=630

Answer (score 0):

The Hanbali madhab allows masturbation on the condition that one is unable to find a lawful spouse as far as I'm aware, and the Hanafi madhab allows masturbation on the condition that one fears he/she will not be able to control himself/herself and will fall into zina.